# Online 3D object editor

Tags: html, 3d

Is there an online 3D object (.stl or .obj) viewer/editor (free or not) which gives to the user the possiblity of uploading a 3D object and making some modifications like smoothing etc ?

After my searchs, I found ShapeDiver which is the perfect tool but, their price policy is not adapted, you can pay a fortune in just one day if a client want to play with 3D models.

https://www.shapediver.com/

I finally found this but too slow :

https://makeprintable.com/

Could someone please advice me a web tool which can make the work ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding ShapeDiver**

[ShapeDiver](https://app.shapediver.com/) works with a session-based pricing. It is primarily used in the context of eCommerce, where sessions are usually short, but its pricing model also accomodates long user sessions: in that case, credits are spent for each 10 minute period spent in the viewer.

On average, this means that the cost of users playing with a tool based on ShapeDiver amounts to 30 cents per hour. You can also prepay credits at a lower price to reduce the bills further.

Of course, the price will grow with your user base, but as you will see below there might not be a cheaper and flexible option to implement the tool you need at the moment.

**Alternatives**

Depending on which modifications you want the users to be able to make, there are several routes you could go. If it's just about smoothing, it should be possible to find or have someone implement a solution, using [Laplacian smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_smoothing) for example, directly in WebGL. If you need more variety of modifications and/or complex operations, you could give a try to online tools like [Vectary](https://www.vectary.com/) (subdivision modelling) or [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com/) (full online CAD system), but you will hit a pricing roadblock again, and it is not clear that you can use such tools to easily build user-friendly interfaces.

I guess you should start by defining with more precision what you and your users need to do before making an informed decision.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for this response. I find this very usefull. The main problem is that the application in which we are going to use the 3D tool will be used by our clients. And I Don't know how many clients will use the system. With for exemple 1000 client who will upload 10 model per day (and at the end, if they don't order every configuration), we can pay more than we earn. I saw in your profile that you are co founder at ShapeDiver. Don't you have an idea of a fix price per month or year in your roadmap ? Thanks again.